# How to create the correspond columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got the data like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict  = {'a':[5,2,4,5,3,3,1,2,3],
             'name':['Jack','jon',"tom",'lazzy','mack','zack','makilo','drag','maiko']}
data_01 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
input:
    a   name
0   5   Jack
1   2   jon
2   4   tom
3   5   lazzy
4   3   mack
5   3   zack
6   1   makilo
7   2   drag
8   3   maiko
```

I hope the output should have 3 columns `'good','mid','poor'` which the a `>3,==3,<3`
The expect output should be:

```
a name good mid poor
5 Jack 1    0   0
2 jon  0    0   1
4 tom  1    0   0 
5 lazzy 1   0   0
3 mack 0    1   0 
....
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I'm going to use `np.sign` on `data_01.a - 3`

  - This returns `-1` when `< 3`, `0` when `== 3`, and `1` when `> 3`
- I then use these as indices on a labels array

  ```
  labels = np.array(['mid', 'good', 'poor'])
  ```
- When I slice, the `0` maps to `'mid'`, `1` maps to `'good'` and `-1` maps to `'poor'`
- Finally, I use `pd.get_dummies` to create dummy columns.

---

```
labels = np.array(['mid', 'good', 'poor'])

data_01.join(pd.get_dummies(labels[np.sign(data_01.a - 3)]))

   a    name  good  mid  poor
0  5    Jack     1    0     0
1  2     jon     0    0     1
2  4     tom     1    0     0
3  5   lazzy     1    0     0
4  3    mack     0    1     0
5  3    zack     0    1     0
6  1  makilo     0    0     1
7  2    drag     0    0     1
8  3   maiko     0    1     0
```

---

**Alternative 1**
This uses `np.eye` to generate the dummy columns.  I create dictionary to tie the dummies to labels and pass the dictionary to `pd.DataFrame.assign`

```
dum = dict(zip(
    ['mid', 'good', 'poor'],
    np.eye(3, dtype=int)[:, np.sign(data_01.a - 3)]
))

data_01.assign(**dum)

   a    name  good  mid  poor
0  5    Jack     1    0     0
1  2     jon     0    0     1
2  4     tom     1    0     0
3  5   lazzy     1    0     0
4  3    mack     0    1     0
5  3    zack     0    1     0
6  1  makilo     0    0     1
7  2    drag     0    0     1
8  3   maiko     0    1     0
```

---

**Alternative 2**
I use `np.eye` again but this time, I create a data frame from scratch and use `pd.DataFrame.join` to attach it to `data_01`

```
dum = pd.DataFrame(
    np.eye(3, dtype=int)[np.sign(data_01.a - 3)],
    data_01.index, ['mid', 'good', 'poor']
)

data_01.join(dum)

   a    name  mid  good  poor
0  5    Jack    0     1     0
1  2     jon    0     0     1
2  4     tom    0     1     0
3  5   lazzy    0     1     0
4  3    mack    1     0     0
5  3    zack    1     0     0
6  1  makilo    0     0     1
7  2    drag    0     0     1
8  3   maiko    1     0     0
```

Comment: Ha, beat me by miles!

Comment: Well, I better do your answer justice and explain myself a bit more (-:

Comment: Also using -1, 0 and 1 to index into labels is very neat trick, will have to remember that!

Comment: @AndyHayden if you were interested.  I added an alternative to `pd.get_dummies`

Answer (score 2):

If need count values:

```
s = np.select([data_01['a'] < 3, data_01['a'] > 3], ['poor','good'], default='mid')

df = data_01.join(data_01.groupby(['name', s]).size().unstack(fill_value=0), on='name')
print (df)
   a    name  good  mid  poor
0  5    Jack     1    0     0
1  2     jon     0    0     1
2  4     tom     1    0     0
3  5   lazzy     1    0     0
4  3    mack     0    1     0
5  3    zack     0    1     0
6  1  makilo     0    0     1
7  2    drag     0    0     1
8  3   maiko     0    1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do some comparisons with `numpy`:

```
arr_a = np.array(a)

good = arr_a > 3
mid  = arr_a == 3
poor = arr_a < 3
```

Then append these arrays to your dataframe as columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this , you can use numpy.where  to get the columns conditionally populated

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
data_dict  = {'a':[5,2,4,5,3,3,1,2,3],
             'name':['Jack','jon',"tom",'lazzy','mack','zack','makilo','drag','maiko']}

data_01 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

#This will create columns 'good','mid','poor' all with default values '0'

data_01['good']=0
data_01['mid']=0
data_01['poor']=0

#Here you are setting each column with value '1' , based on the condition 

data_01['good']=np.where(data_01['a'] > 3,1, data_01['good'])
data_01['mid']=np.where(data_01['a'] == 3,1, data_01['mid'])
data_01['poor']=np.where(data_01['a'] < 3,1, data_01['poor'])
print data_01
```

Output is

```
 a    name  good  mid  poor
0  5    Jack     1    0     0
1  2     jon     0    0     1
2  4     tom     1    0     0
3  5   lazzy     1    0     0
4  3    mack     0    1     0
5  3    zack     0    1     0
6  1  makilo     0    0     1
7  2    drag     0    0     1
8  3   maiko     0    1     0
```